# Pandas объединени и смещение столбцов

Tags: python, pandas

Имею df следующего формата:

```
             A        |            B                        
     A1          A2   |     A1         A2       A3
0    099       54135       099        54135     INE
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно объединить колонки А1 и привести к подобному формату:

```
             A        |            B                        
 A1 |            A2   |       A2       A3
 099|           54135         54135     INE
```

соответственно df может содержать колонки C, D и т.п. нужно объединять колонки А1 в одну колонку и смещать в лево.
Спасибо!

данный дф формируется из словаря

```
l = [
 {'A':{'A1': '099', 'A2': '54135'}},
 {'B':{'A1': '099', 'A2': '54135', 'A3': 'INE'}}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
res = pd.concat([df[x].apply(pd.Series).
                 dropna(how="all").reset_index(drop=True) for x in df.columns],
                axis=1, keys=df.columns).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
```

Comment: Ох, сложновато с мультииндексом работать. Надо MaxU ждать видимо опять )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подумал, что можно сделать следующим образом:

1. Разбить датафрейм на группы **A**, **B**, **C** и т.д.
2. Для каждой группы установить колонку **A1** в качестве индекса.
3. Объединить все датафреймы в один. Колонка **A1** станет общим индексом.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
     A           B             C              D            
    A1     A2   A1  A2   A3   A1   A4   A5   A1     A6   A7
0  099  54135  099  33  INE  099  236  INE  099  44223  INE

In [4]: pd.concat([group
   ...:            .set_index((name, 'A1'))
   ...:            .rename_axis(index={(name, 'A1'): 'A1'})
   ...:            for name, group in df.groupby(level=0, axis='columns')],
   ...:           axis='columns')
Out[4]: 
         A   B         C           D     
        A2  A2   A3   A4   A5     A6   A7
A1                                       
099  54135  33  INE  236  INE  44223  INE
```

Comment: по-моему это отличное решение)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо )